Adjusting a multivariate predictive model for drifting seasonalities
This question is a repost of a question originally asked in Quantitative Finance. I was alerted that this would be a more appropriate place for it.
I have a time series of daily observations that get aggregated to a monthly periodicity. The monthly series exhibits strong and reliable seasonal patterns and is well suited for adjusting with X-13ARIMA-SEATS. X-13ARIMA-SEATS can generate forecasts and the OOS forecasts are generally good, with an error distribution that is close to symmetrical and a mean median and mode close to zero, a stationary mean variance and no discernible serial autocorrelation.
Now that I have a good forecast for the month ahead, I would like to forecast the individual days. The daily data is restricted to a subset of business days that is known in advance. Within the month there is additional seasonal patterns, and I am trying to predict these patterns. Many of the patterns are highly reliable across time and the seasonality of a month will very strongly resemble the seasonality of that same month on a different year that had the same weekday pattern.
The approach I am taking is to use the percentage of the monthly total that corresponds to any given day as the dependent variable and then a series of binary independent variables that describe the seasonality. Because the features are mostly consistent across months, the coefficients can be calculated using all of the months combined. The issue is that the seasonality changes with time, albeit very gradually, leading to two problems:

The accuracy of the daily predictions declines with time
Older observations become less useful for calculating the
coefficients.

A simplified example is this: I am counting cars at a parking garage, with my goal being to forecast how many cars will park each day. Prior to the month starting I have a forecast for the total number of cars that will park. From prior observations I know that each weekday has different level of utilization, days before a holiday are quiet and month end and mid-month are busy but also that other patterns change with time (busy Wednesdays could gradually become busy Tuesdays)
I am trying to find the "sweet spot" for training the regression and it occurs to me that the best way to do it would be to assign some sort of decay to observations so that their influence on the coefficient declines with time. One thing I have been doing is calculating the coefficients every month based on a smaller rolling sample of recent history and then exponentially weighing the coefficients with the prior month's coefficient. So far, it kind-of works but it seems clunky and clumsy, and it still has trouble adapting to new patterns. I've also tried simply reusing the values from the last month that had the same weekday pattern which gets a lot right with little to no work, but is not accurate enough to be useful.
I was hoping for suggestions as to what to look into to improve this process. I've tried searching quite a bit, but I cannot seem to figure out what to search to find something helpful. Below is some R pseudocode to hopefully illustrate a little what I am currently doing. I am hoping there is a method where I can build the weighting into the model itself. I know I could just replicate observations based on their recency (more recent, more copies) to mock this by stuffing the training data, but that seems incredibly sus? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

training_data <- daily_data |> 
  filter(date >= max(date) - months(24)) |>
  group_by(period = floor_date(date, 'month') |>
  mutate(value = value/sum(value)) |> 
  ungroup() |> inner_join(features, by = 'date')

model <- lm(value ~ feat1 + feat2 + feat3, data = training_data)
#in practice this is a matrix not a data frame, this is just an example
model_coef <- pivot_wider(enframe(coef(model)))
previous_coefs <- union_all(
  previous_coefs, 
  add_column(model_coef, date = max(training_data$period))
)
ewma_lambda <- 0.85
weighted_coefs <- mutate(
  across(
    -date,
    \(x) accumulate(
      x,
      \(.x, .y)(1 - ewma_lambda) * .y + ewma_lambda * .x
    )
  )
)

